# How to import a private key into a Java keystore without knowning the password

Tags: java, keystore, keytool

I have a private key in PEM format, protected by a password (there is also a certificate for the key). Is it possible to import this key into a Java keystore without knowing it's password?

Knowing the password I would do the following:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.pem -inkey key.pem > server.p12
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore server.p12 -destkeystore server.jks -srcstoretype pkcs12
```

But I'd like to skip password input and re-use the existing password.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

No, the private key is encrypted, and the passphrase must be supplied to decrypt the key before it is imported.

Comment: Not with keytool. Custom code directly using JCA `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec` can handle unencrypted PKCS8 (and only that) -- although to put it in a keystore you need the cert(s) also.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 you are right...keytool will not allow a key entry by itself. My Answer assumed that OP is repacking the unencrypted key as part of his import process. Updated now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Not Possible**.

The whole point of having the `PrivateKey` protected is to not let anyone gain access to it unless they know the password that unlocks it.